# Loading a 32 bit integer image with opencv

Tags: python, c++, opencv, scipy

I have 32 bit grayscale image data saved in tif files. It stems from background corrected CCD data so the values can also be negative.

Working in Python, scipy.misc.imread can load the file with no problems. With opencv however, I didn't manage to get the correct data, it loads all values as NaN, no matter what options I pass imread.

My main code is in C++, so I cannot use SciPy and have so far been happy with OpenCV but here it fails me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Add the code to load the image in your question

Comment: Mat1i img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);

Comment: Not sure if the code would be very helpful. I used:
Mat img = imread("img_file", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
and also tried all the other variants (COLOR, GRAYSCALE), nothing worked. I fear openCV cannot handle 32bit integer images

Comment: can you post the image so I can try?

Comment: `img = cv2.imread('32-bit.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game, I think this is your issue:
[What happens when show a signed image in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851462/what-happens-when-show-a-signed-image-in-opencv)

-because I'm running into it trying to read 32 bit signed PNGs and OpenCV is (apparently) truncating them.