# What happens when show a signed image in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

The documentation of `imshow` only writes:

> - If the image is 8-bit unsigned, it is displayed as is.
> - If the image is 16-bit unsigned or 32-bit integer, the pixels are divided by 256. That is, the value range [0,255*256] is mapped to [0,255].
> - If the image is 32-bit floating-point, the pixel values are multiplied by 255. That is, the value range [0,1] is mapped to [0,255].

No define behavior about signed image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. There is small documentation issue. 
I will try to extend the documentation:

1. If the image is 8-bit signed (CV_8S), it will be converted to unsigned char just adding 128 and display as is.
2. If the image is 16-bit signed (CV_16S), the pixels are divided by 256 and shifted by 128.
3. If the image is 32-bit signed (CV_32S), the pixels not in range [0,255*256] are truncated.
4. If the image is 32-bit floating-point (CV_32F), the pixels not in range [0, 1] are truncated.

You may see code which handles such cases [here](https://github.com/akarsakov/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgcodecs/src/utils.cpp#L622).

Comment: it will be nice if someone will update [documentation of OpenCV](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/highgui/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp#L344-L348)

Comment: it will be nice if someone will update